# Add st, nd, rd and th (ordinal) suffix to a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

I would like to dynamically generate a string of text based on a current day. So, for example, if it is day 1 then I would like my code to generate = "Its the <dynamic>1*<dynamic string>*st*</dynamic string>*</dynamic>".

There are 12 days in total so I have done the following:

1. I've set up a for loop which loops through the 12 days.
2. In my html I have given my element a unique id with which to target it, see below:

   ```
   <h1 id="dynamicTitle" class="CustomFont leftHeading shadow">On The <span></span> <em>of rest of generic text</em></h1>
   ```
3. Then, inside my for loop I have the following code:

   ```
   $("#dynamicTitle span").html(i);
   var day = i;
   if (day == 1) {
       day = i + "st";
   } else if (day == 2) {
       day = i + "nd"
   } else if (day == 3) {
       day = i + "rd"
   }
   ```

*UPDATE*

This is the entire for loop as requested:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        var classy = "";
        if (daysTilDate(i + 19) > 0) {
            classy = "future";
            $("#Day" + i).addClass(classy);
            $("#mainHeading").html("");
            $("#title").html("");
            $("#description").html("");
        } else if (daysTilDate(i + 19) < 0) {
            classy = "past";
            $("#Day" + i).addClass(classy);
            $("#title").html("");
            $("#description").html("");
            $("#mainHeading").html("");
            $(".cta").css('display', 'none');
            $("#Day" + i + " .prizeLink").attr("href", "" + i + ".html");
        } else {
            classy = "current";
            $("#Day" + i).addClass(classy);
            $("#title").html(headings[i - 1]);
            $("#description").html(descriptions[i - 1]);
            $(".cta").css('display', 'block');
            $("#dynamicImage").attr("src", ".." + i + ".jpg");
            $("#mainHeading").html("");
            $(".claimPrize").attr("href", "" + i + ".html");
            $("#dynamicTitle span").html(i);
            var day = i;
            if (day == 1) {
                day = i + "st";
            } else if (day == 2) {
                day = i + "nd"
            } else if (day == 3) {
                day = i + "rd"
            } else if (day) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your source code is short enough, would you mind posting the full thing, and also saying exactly what is wrong or what's confusing you?

Comment: What is it that your code does/doesn't do currently?  You did not clearly state what's going wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing the code shown is the content of an `if` block which is further contained by the loop? Show more code....

Comment: @MrCode - Yes you are correct. I have updated the post to include the entire for loop. I hope this clears it up!

Comment: neat and it works well.

Comment: A more native and locale friendly answer as of 2021 would be
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57518703/80428

Answer (score 539, accepted):

For English ordinal suffix, the [rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator#English) are as follows:

> - st is used with numbers ending in 1 (e.g. 1st, pronounced first)
> - nd is used with numbers ending in 2 (e.g. 92nd, pronounced ninety-second)
> - rd is used with numbers ending in 3 (e.g. 33rd, pronounced thirty-third)
> - As an exception to the above rules, numbers ending with 11, 12, and 13 use -th (e.g. 11th, pronounced eleventh, 112th, pronounced one
>   hundred [and] twelfth)
> - th is used for all other numbers (e.g. 9th, pronounced ninth)

The following JavaScript code accomplishes this:

```js
function ordinal_suffix_of(i) {
    let j = i % 10,
        k = i % 100;
    if (j === 1 && k !== 11) {
        return i + "st";
    }
    if (j === 2 && k !== 12) {
        return i + "nd";
    }
    if (j === 3 && k !== 13) {
        return i + "rd";
    }
    return i + "th";
}

// output for numbers between 0-115

for (let n = 0; n <= 115; n++) {
    console.log(n + " " + ordinal_suffix_of(n));
}
```

Comment: It worked really well for mine as well: dateString = monthNames[newValue.getUTCMonth()] + " " + numberSuffix(newValue.getUTCDate()) + ", " + newValue.getUTCFullYear();

Comment: This answer seems to have evolved perfectly. Thank you to all contributors.

Comment: I sqeezed it as an ES6 lambda for no real reason: `n=>n+(n%10==1&&n%100!=11?'st':n%10==2&&n%100!=12?'nd':n%10==3&&n%100!=13?'rd':'th')`

Comment: @Anomaly funnily enough, after ~π/2 years later I can still read it.

Comment: Although the other answers are more verbose, I'm all for clean code.

Comment: I added `i = Number(i)` since one of my charts sends the number as a string.

Comment: Doesn't handle negative numbers, returning "th" as the suffix for all numbers less than 1. See [Константин Ван's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57518703/257182) answer for a general solution.

Comment: @robg never seen ordinal suffix used with negative numbers. Anyway, handling those numbers is trivial. Or may be not. https://english.stackexchange.com/q/326604/9459

Comment: Nor have I, but I'm OK with "the -1st item" as "the minus first item" rather than "minus oneth item", which really is clumsy. I guess where there is no convention it's up to trail blazers to create one. ;-)

Comment: here is another ES6 lamda, shorter but dumber: `n => n + (n % 100 - n % 10 === 10 || n % 10 < 1 || n % 10 > 3 ? 'th' : [0, 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][n % 10]);`, although  i bet extracting n%10 as a const is probably more efficient.

Comment: @Megandardery Slightly shorter, slightly dumber: `n=>n+['th','st','nd','rd'][n%100-n%10-10&&n%10<4?n%10:0]`

Comment: I love seeing the code-golf in the comments. If it's dumb but it works, then it's not dumb. Therefore, I use the one by @PotassiumIon to confuse my boss.

Comment: This does not change the answer, but rather tidies it up a bit by removing unneeded curly braces and using string interpolation.  Just thought I'd share.  I appreciate this solution as it's easier to understand at a glance and therefore easier to maintain.  With proper line breaks (that you can't see in these comments), this is super clean. 
function GetOrdinalString(i) {
 const j = i % 10, k = i % 100;
 if (j === 1 && k !== 11) return `${i}st`;
 if (j === 2 && k !== 12) return `${i}nd`;
 if (j === 3 && k !== 13) return `${i}rd`;
 return `${i}th`;
}

Answer (score 254):

From [Shopify](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/ordinal-number-in-javascript-1st-2nd-3rd-4th-29259)

```js
function getNumberWithOrdinal(n) {
  var s = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"],
      v = n % 100;
  return n + (s[(v - 20) % 10] || s[v] || s[0]);
}

[-4,-1,0,1,2,3,4,10,11,12,13,14,20,21,22,100,101,111].forEach(
  n => console.log(n + ' -> ' + getNumberWithOrdinal(n))
);
```

Comment: Adding explanation can make it a better answer!

Comment: @Pugazh **A.** find s[v%10] if >= 20 (20th...99th), **B.** if not found, try s[v] (0th..3rd), **C.** if still not found, use s[0] (4th..19th)

Comment: why the double get in the function name though?

Answer (score 111):

#### Minimal one-line approach for ordinal suffixes

```
function nth(n){return["st","nd","rd"][((n+90)%100-10)%10-1]||"th"}
```

(this is for positive integers, see below for other variations)

#### Explanation

Start with an array with the suffixes `["st", "nd", "rd"]`. We want to map integers ending in 1, 2, 3 (but not ending in 11, 12, 13) to the indexes 0, 1, 2.

Other integers (including those ending in 11, 12, 13) can be mapped to anything else—indexes not found in the array will evaluate to `undefined`. This is falsy in javascript and with the use of logical or (`|| "th"`) the expression will return `"th"` for these integers, which is exactly what we want.

The expression `((n + 90) % 100 - 10) % 10 - 1` does the mapping. Breaking it down:

- `(n + 90) % 100`: This expression takes the input integer − 10 mod 100, mapping 10 to 0, ... 99 to 89, 0 to 90, ..., 9 to 99. Now the integers ending in 11, 12, 13 are at the lower end (mapped to 1, 2, 3).
- `- 10`: Now 10 is mapped to −10, 19 to −1, 99 to 79, 0 to 80, ... 9 to 89. The integers ending in 11, 12, 13 are mapped to negative integers (−9, −8, −7).
- `% 10`: Now all integers ending in 1, 2, or 3 are mapped to 1, 2, 3. All other integers are mapped to something else (11, 12, 13 are still mapped to −9, −8, −7).
- `- 1`: Subtracting one gives the final mapping of 1, 2, 3 to 0, 1, 2.

#### Verifying that it works

```js
function nth(n){return["st","nd","rd"][((n+90)%100-10)%10-1]||"th"}

//test integers from 1 to 124
for(var r = [], i = 1; i < 125; i++) r.push(i + nth(i));

//output result
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = r.join('<br>');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

#### Variations

Allowing negative integers:

```
function nth(n){return["st","nd","rd"][(((n<0?-n:n)+90)%100-10)%10-1]||"th"}
```

```js
function nth(n){return["st","nd","rd"][(((n<0?-n:n)+90)%100-10)%10-1]||"th"}

//test integers from 15 to -124
for(var r = [], i = 15; i > -125; i--) r.push(i + nth(i));

//output result
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = r.join('<br>');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

In ES6 fat arrow syntax (anonymous function):

```
n=>["st","nd","rd"][(((n<0?-n:n)+90)%100-10)%10-1]||"th"
```

Answer (score 96):

## `Intl.PluralRules`, the *standard* method.

I would just like to drop the canonical way of doing this in here, as nobody seems to know it. Do not reinvent the wheel.

If you want your code to be

- self-documenting
- easy to localize
- with the modern standard

― **this is the way to go.**

```js
const english_ordinal_rules = new Intl.PluralRules("en", {type: "ordinal"});
const suffixes = {
    one: "st",
    two: "nd",
    few: "rd",
    other: "th"
};
function ordinal(number/*: number */) {
    const category = english_ordinal_rules.select(number);
    const suffix = suffixes[category];
    return (number + suffix);
} // -> string

const test = Array(201)
    .fill()
    .map((_, index) => index - 100)
    .map(ordinal)
    .join(" ");
console.log(test);
```

- [The `Intl.PluralRules` constructor (Draft ECMA-402)](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-intl-pluralrules-constructor)
- [Unicode’s six plurality categories](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/cldr-spec/plural-rules)

---

### Code-golf

While I **do not recommend** golfing with your code and killing the readability, I came up with one for those golfers (92 bytes):

```js
n=>n+{e:"st",o:"nd",w:"rd",h:"th"}[new Intl.PluralRules("en",{type:"ordinal"}).select(n)[2]]
```

Comment: @RobG Thomas Langkaas's answer, the example that he says allows negative numbers, doesn't allow them?

Comment: @RobG I still like this one best, in part because you can localize it.

Comment: @RobG, @BobRhodes, did you try the variation for negative numbers `function nth(n){return["st","nd","rd"][(((n<0?-n:n)+90)%100-10)%10-1]||"th"}`? It works fine for me, I also added code to demo that now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution! Love when I can leverage pre-existing functionality.

Comment: For a version of this that plays nicely with type checking (e.g. TypeScript) see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76265684/223225

Answer (score 29):

You can use the [moment libraries local data functions](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/).

**Code:**

```
moment.localeData().ordinal(1)
//1st
```

Comment: Cleanest way to do it if you are already using moment in your codebase!

Answer (score 10):

By splitting the number into an array and reversing we can easily check the last 2 digits of the number using `array[0]` and `array[1]`.

If a number is in the teens `array[1] = 1`  it requires "th".

```
function getDaySuffix(num)
{
    var array = ("" + num).split("").reverse(); // E.g. 123 = array("3","2","1")
    
    if (array[1] != "1") { // Number is not in the teens
        switch (array[0]) {
            case "1": return "st";
            case "2": return "nd";
            case "3": return "rd";
        }
    }
    
    return "th";
}
```

Comment: You have to exclude 11, 12, 13

Comment: @psx That's what the condition on line 5 is for.

Comment: "Number is in the teens" should be "Number is not in the teens". :-)

Answer (score 7):

You've only got 12 days? I'd be tempted to make it just a simple lookup array:

```
var suffixes = ['','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th','th'];
```

then

```
var i = 2;
var day = i + suffixes[i]; // result: '2nd'
```

or

```
var i = 8;
var day = i + suffixes[i]; // result: '8th'
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I couldnt get the suffix to match the day so i just populated the array with,both, the numbers and the suffix which works perfectly. I then simply called it like `$("#dynamicTitle span").html(suffix[i-1]);`

Comment: Since everything from the 4th index onward is the same, you can do `suffixes = ['th','st','nd','rd']; d = i + (suffixes[i] || suffixes[0]);`. :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
function getSuffix(n) {return n < 11 || n > 13 ? ['st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th'][Math.min((n - 1) % 10, 3)] : 'th'}
```

Comment: Nice little oneliner, just a bit hard to understand

Comment: Fails where n == 0 due to `n - 1` part (returns undefined). Also fails for numbers greater than 110, e.g. `getSuffix(111)` returns "st".  It does solve the OP's problem where numbers are 1 to 12, but is not a general solution. :-(

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this function to solve this problem:

```
// this is for adding the ordinal suffix, turning 1, 2 and 3 into 1st, 2nd and 3rd
Number.prototype.addSuffix=function(){
    var n=this.toString().split('.')[0];
    var lastDigits=n.substring(n.length-2);
    //add exception just for 11, 12 and 13
    if(lastDigits==='11' || lastDigits==='12' || lastDigits==='13'){
        return this+'th';
    }
    switch(n.substring(n.length-1)){
        case '1': return this+'st';
        case '2': return this+'nd';
        case '3': return this+'rd';
        default : return this+'th';
    }
};
```

With this you can just put `.addSuffix()` to any number and it will result in what you want. For example:

```
var number=1234;
console.log(number.addSuffix());
// console will show: 1234th
```

Comment: I think `number` in this string `var lastDigits=n.substring(number.length-2);` should be changed to `this`

Comment: it should be `n` instead of `this`, but thanks for pointing that bug out! :)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative version of the ordinal function could be as follows:

```
function toCardinal(num) {
    var ones = num % 10;
    var tens = num % 100;

    if (tens < 11 || tens > 13) {
        switch (ones) {
            case 1:
                return num + "st";
            case 2:
                return num + "nd";
            case 3:
                return num + "rd";
        }
    }

    return num + "th";
}
```

The variables are named more explicitly, uses camel case convention, and might be faster.

Comment: This will not work for localized code bases however.

Answer (score 3):

```
const getOrdinalNum = (n) => n + (n > 0 ? ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][(n > 3 && n < 21) || n % 10 > 3 ? 0 : n % 10] : '');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

A version of the [`Intl.PluralRules` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57518703/223225) that TypeScript type checking approves of:

```js
const englishOrdinalRules = new Intl.PluralRules('en', { type: 'ordinal' })
/**
 * Format a number as an ordinal, e.g. `3` to `3rd`.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/a/57518703/223225
 * @param {number} number To format
 */
export function formatNumberOrdinal(number) {
    const category = englishOrdinalRules.select(number)

    switch (category) {
        case 'one': {
            return `${number}st`
        }

        case 'two': {
            return `${number}nd`
        }

        case 'few': {
            return `${number}rd`
        }

        default: {
            return `${number}th`
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this simple function the other day.  Although for a date you don't need the larger numbers, this will cater for higher values too (1013th, 36021st etc...)

```
var fGetSuffix = function(nPos){

    var sSuffix = "";

    switch (nPos % 10){
        case 1:
            sSuffix = (nPos % 100 === 11) ? "th" : "st";
            break;
        case 2:
            sSuffix = (nPos % 100 === 12) ? "th" : "nd";
            break;
        case 3:
            sSuffix = (nPos % 100 === 13) ? "th" : "rd";
            break;
        default:
            sSuffix = "th";
            break;
    }

    return sSuffix;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`function ordsfx(a){return["th","st","nd","rd"][(a=~~(a<0?-a:a)%100)>10&&a<14||(a%=10)>3?0:a]}`

See annotated version at https://gist.github.com/furf/986113#file-annotated-js

Short, sweet, and efficient, just like utility functions should be. Works with any signed/unsigned integer/float. (Even though I can't imagine a need to ordinalize floats)

Answer (score 1):

Strongly recommend the excellent [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) library.  Fast, modular, immutable, works with standard dates.

```
import * as DateFns from 'date-fns';

const ordinalInt = DateFns.format(someInt, 'do');
```

See date-fns docs: https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.9/docs/format

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option.

```js
function getOrdinalSuffix(day) {
        
    if(/^[2-3]?1$/.test(day)){
     return 'st';
    } else if(/^[2-3]?2$/.test(day)){
     return 'nd';
    } else if(/^[2-3]?3$/.test(day)){
     return 'rd';
    } else {
     return 'th';
    }
        
}
    
console.log(getOrdinalSuffix('1'));
console.log(getOrdinalSuffix('13'));
console.log(getOrdinalSuffix('22'));
console.log(getOrdinalSuffix('33'));
```

Notice the exception for the teens? Teens are so akward!

Edit: Forgot about 11th and 12th

Answer (score 0):

Old one I made for my stuff...

```
function convertToOrdinal(number){
    if (number !=1){
        var numberastext = number.ToString();
        var endchar = numberastext.Substring(numberastext.Length - 1);
        if (number>9){
            var secondfromendchar = numberastext.Substring(numberastext.Length - 1);
            secondfromendchar = numberastext.Remove(numberastext.Length - 1);
        }
        var suffix = "th";
        var digit = int.Parse(endchar);
        switch (digit){
            case 3:
                if(secondfromendchar != "1"){
                    suffix = "rd";
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                if(secondfromendchar != "1"){
                    suffix = "nd";
                    break;
                }
            case 1:
                if(secondfromendchar != "1"){
                    suffix = "st";
                    break;
                }
            default:
                suffix = "th";
                break;
         }
            return number+suffix+" ";
     } else {
            return;
     }
}
```

Comment: Add some description about above code. It would help much more than a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function for higher numbers and all test cases

```
function numberToOrdinal(num) {
    if (num === 0) {
        return '0'
    };
    let i = num.toString(), j = i.slice(i.length - 2), k = i.slice(i.length - 1);
    if (j >= 10 && j <= 20) {
        return (i + 'th')
    } else if (j > 20 && j < 100) {
        if (k == 1) {
            return (i + 'st')
        } else if (k == 2) {
            return (i + 'nd')
        } else if (k == 3) {
            return (i + 'rd')
        } else {
            return (i + 'th')
        }
    } else if (j == 1) {
        return (i + 'st')
    } else if (j == 2) {
        return (i + 'nd')
    } else if (j == 3) {
        return (i + 'rd')
    } else {
        return (i + 'th')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach (I don't think the other answers do this). I'm not sure whether I love it or hate it, but it works!

```
export function addDaySuffix(day: number) { 
  const suffixes =
      '  stndrdthththththththththththththththththstndrdthththththththst';
    const startIndex = day * 2;

    return `${day}${suffixes.substring(startIndex, startIndex + 2)}`;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to quote the answer available in the [link](https://leancrew.com/all-this/2020/06/ordinal-numerals-and-javascript/)

```
function ordinal(n) {
  var s = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"];
  var v = n%100;
  return n + (s[(v-20)%10] || s[v] || s[0]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to provide a functional answer to this question to complement the existing answer:

```
const ordinalSuffix = ['st', 'nd', 'rd']
const addSuffix = n => n + (ordinalSuffix[(n - 1) % 10] || 'th')
const numberToOrdinal = n => `${n}`.match(/1\d$/) ? n + 'th' : addSuffix(n)
```

we've created an array of the special values, the important thing to remember is arrays have a zero based index so ordinalSuffix[0] is equal to 'st'.

Our function numberToOrdinal checks if the number ends in a teen number in which case append the number with 'th' as all then numbers ordinals are 'th'. In the event that the number is not a teen we pass the number to addSuffix which adds the number to the ordinal which is determined by if the number minus 1 (because we're using a zero based index) mod 10 has a remainder of 2 or less it's taken from the array, otherwise it's 'th'.

sample output:

```
numberToOrdinal(1) // 1st
numberToOrdinal(2) // 2nd
numberToOrdinal(3) // 3rd
numberToOrdinal(4) // 4th
numberToOrdinal(5) // 5th
numberToOrdinal(6) // 6th
numberToOrdinal(7) // 7th
numberToOrdinal(8) // 8th
numberToOrdinal(9) // 9th
numberToOrdinal(10) // 10th
numberToOrdinal(11) // 11th
numberToOrdinal(12) // 12th
numberToOrdinal(13) // 13th
numberToOrdinal(14) // 14th
numberToOrdinal(101) // 101st
```

Answer (score -1):

**I strongly recommend this, it is super easy and straightforward to read. I hope it help?**

- It avoid the use of negative integer i.e number less than 1 and return false
- It return 0 if input is 0

```
function numberToOrdinal(n) {

  let result;

  if(n < 0){
    return false;
  }else if(n === 0){
    result = "0";
  }else if(n > 0){

    let nToString = n.toString();
    let lastStringIndex = nToString.length-1;
    let lastStringElement = nToString[lastStringIndex];

    if( lastStringElement == "1" && n % 100 !== 11 ){
      result = nToString + "st";
    }else if( lastStringElement == "2" && n % 100 !== 12 ){
      result = nToString + "nd";
    }else if( lastStringElement == "3" && n % 100 !== 13 ){
      result = nToString + "rd";
    }else{
      result = nToString + "th";
    }

  }

  return result;
}

console.log(numberToOrdinal(-111));
console.log(numberToOrdinal(0));
console.log(numberToOrdinal(11));
console.log(numberToOrdinal(15));
console.log(numberToOrdinal(21));
console.log(numberToOrdinal(32));
console.log(numberToOrdinal(43));
console.log(numberToOrdinal(70));
console.log(numberToOrdinal(111));
console.log(numberToOrdinal(300));
console.log(numberToOrdinal(101));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
false
0
11th
15th
21st
32nd
43rd
70th
111th
300th
101st
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be done as follow:

```
function convertNumberToOrdinal(inputNumber) {
    if (typeof inputNumber !== 'number') {
        return 'Input is not a valid';
    }

    if (inputNumber % 1 !== 0) {
        return 'Input is not an integer';
    }

    if (inputNumber < 0) {
        return 'Input must be a non-negative integer';
    }

    const lastDigit = inputNumber % 10;
    const lastTwoDigits = inputNumber % 100;

    if (lastTwoDigits >= 11 && lastTwoDigits <= 13) {
        return inputNumber + 'th';
    }

    switch (lastDigit) {
        case 1:
            return inputNumber + 'st';
        case 2:
            return inputNumber + 'nd';
        case 3:
            return inputNumber + 'rd';
        default:
            return inputNumber + 'th';
    }
}

// Example usage:
console.log(convertNumberToOrdinal(1));   // Output: "1st"
console.log(convertNumberToOrdinal(22));  // Output: "22nd"
console.log(convertNumberToOrdinal(33));  // Output: "33rd"
console.log(convertNumberToOrdinal(104)); // Output: "104th"
```

Answer (score -2):

This is for one liners and lovers of es6

```
let i= new Date().getDate 

// I can be any number, for future sake we'll use 9

const j = I % 10;
const k = I % 100;

i = `${i}${j === 1 &&  k !== 11 ? 'st' : j === 2 && k !== 12 ? 'nd' : j === 3 && k !== 13 ? 'rd' : 'th'}`}

console.log(i) //9th
```

Another option for +be number would be:

```
console.log(["st","nd","rd"][((i+90)%100-10)%10-1]||"th"]
```

Also to get rid of the ordinal prefix just use these:

```
console.log(i.parseInt("8th"))

console.log(i.parseFloat("8th"))
```

feel free to modify to suit you need

Comment: Part of this answer is just copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39466341/6738706) without credit.

Answer (score -8):

```html
<p>31<sup>st</sup> March 2015</p>
```

You can use

`1<sup>st</sup>
2<sup>nd</sup>
3<sup>rd</sup>
4<sup>th</sup>`

for positioning the suffix

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking for