# Javascript get english count number

Tags: javascript, algorithm, count

I want a function that takes a number and returns an english count number e.g.:
3 returns 3rd

My working solution:

```
function GetEnglishCount(number) {
    if ((number % 10 == 1) && (number % 100 != 11)) {
        return number + "st";
    }
    else if ((number % 10 == 2) && (number % 100 != 12)) {
        return number + "nd";
    }
    else if ((number % 10 == 3) && (number % 100 != 13)) {
        return number + "rd";
    }
    else {
        return number + "th";
    }
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teu7qrjy/)

Is there a more elegant/accurate way to do this?

Comment: See also http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4707/outputting-ordinal-numbers-1st-2nd-3rd

Comment: What's your concrete problem with this code? You call it a working solution, still you ask for a more accurate one.

Comment: Does one of the solutions to [*Add st, nd, rd and th (ordinal) suffix to a number*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627308/add-st-nd-rd-and-th-ordinal-suffix-to-a-number) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the else chaining, because return ends the function and delete some parenthesis.

```
function GetEnglishCount(number) {
    if (number % 10 === 1 && number % 100 !== 11) {
        return number + "st";
    }
    if (number % 10 === 2 && number % 100 !== 12) {
        return number + "nd";
    }
    if (number % 10 === 3 && number % 100 !== 13) {
        return number + "rd";
    }
    return number + "th";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is one way to write it:

```
function GetEnglishCount(number) {
  if([11,12,13].indexOf(number%100)+1)
    return 'th'
  switch(number%10){
    case 1: return  'st'
    case 2: return 'nd'
    case 3: return 'rd'
  }
  return 'th'
}
```

<kbd>[`Fiddle Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/teu7qrjy/1/)</kbd>