# Correct suffix for a time returned in minutes - Android

Tags: java, android

For context, currently I'm working on a Football game which on the home screen displays a list of [active games](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nihue.png) with the time that has passed.

Currently, I'm getting the `gameTime` from a BaaS and displaying it using modular to determine the suffix like so:

```
int time = obj.getInt("gameTime");

        String tmp;
        switch (time % 10) {
            case 1:
                tmp = "st";
                break;
            case 2:
                tmp = "nd";
                break;
            case 3:
                tmp = "rd";
                break;
            default:
                tmp = "th";
        }

tv.setText(Integer.toString(time) + tmp + " Minutes");
```

But from the image you can see it's not giving the *most accurate* result, I was querying whether there was some form of feature with say for example `JodaTime`? to get an input in minutes and display the correct suffix? if not, do you know of anything?

Comment: It is also accepted to put an apostrophe after the number of minutes i.e. `11' minute`

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE Unfortunately, i'm a mere developer and the choice has been made regarding UI.

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed it by using the same logic as [Javascript - Add st, nd, rd and th (ordinal) suffix to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627308/add-st-nd-rd-and-th-ordinal-suffix-to-a-number)'s accepted answer. I was on the right track.

For future users though, my code is:

```
int time = obj.getInt("gameTime");
String tmp;
int j = time % 10, k = time % 100;

   if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
        tmp = "st";
   } else {
        tmp = "th";
   }

   if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
         tmp = "nd";
   } else {
         tmp = "th";
   }

   if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
        tmp = "rd";
   } else {
        tmp = "th";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will Help you:

```
String timeWithPostfix(int num) {
    String[] suffix = { "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th",
            "th", "th" };
    int m = num % 100;
    return String.valueOf(num) + suffix[(m > 10 && m < 20) ? 0 : (m % 10)];
}
```

Reference : [How do you format the day of the month to say "11th", "21st" or "23rd" in Java? (ordinal indicator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011075/how-do-you-format-the-day-of-the-month-to-say-11th-21st-or-23rd-in-java)

Comment: Thank-you for your feedback, I have determined a solution now similar to the code I've already written. Appreciate the post.