# Angular create dynamic scope in controller(js) & bind in view(html)

Tags: angularjs

I have created this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RpOYN8?p=preview) to show what I'v tried.

```
 $scope.myArray = [{
            "productDetails": {
                "productName": "productname1",
                "qty": 5,
                "pricePerPiece": 20
            },
            "vehiclecategory": "abcd"
        },
        ...
 ]
```

Need to bind the values of each vehicle category for each record.
Have two records per row with Label & it's value that will be bind from key vehiclecategory for each object.

Label will remain as it is since its text will change depending upon internationalization, so it will be a constant that will be coming from properties file as per user location. There will be separate constants file for each location.

Currently have hard code the label value. Need to achieve below sample

(1)First Record : abcd1

(2)Second Record : abcd2

Comment: Have a look at this blog post to see how you can send different labels and make angular decide what to show on ui: http://blog.novanet.no/creating-multilingual-support-using-angularjs/

Comment: what did you want to do ?

Comment: @yaser. I have created internationalization json file for multilingual support my concern is to achieve the key value for the labels as specified in plnkr. But one thing that label text will be differ, for first instead of First Record it might be say My Data, for second Your Info etc & so on.

Comment: @AlainIb. I need to bind the value for each label but the label text will be different not First Record, Second Record, It may be say My Data, Your Info etc & so on.

Comment: have updated the plnkr. I had to create 6 different scope objects. Is it possible to create scope variable dynamically say $scope.label + "key" = my value for the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JohnD answer is correct, you can display the item inside an array using `ngRepeat` but if you want to add `ordinal numbers` you can have a look in this post "[Add st, nd, rd and th (ordinal) suffix to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627308/add-st-nd-rd-and-th-ordinal-suffix-to-a-number)"

Comment: @prxygen. Sorry. The label text will not be in same format, meaning not First Record, Second Record & so on. It will be different name which will be unique say for first it will My Data, second Test Info & so on. Since the label value won't be in same format i guess ng-repeat won't be an option. Let me know if still unclear

Comment: have updated the plnkr. I had to create 6 different scope objects. Is it possible to create scope variable dynamically say $scope.label + "key" = my value for the key.

Comment: did you try to add another key value pair in `myArray`? lets say `"vehiclecategory": "abcd" , "label":"My Data"` then call it using ngRepeat. Sorry if we can't answer your question directly because it is quite unclear

Comment: oh yes you can create a dynamic `$scope` to achieve this inject `$parse` in your controller. just like this
`var label = "dynamicLabel" + "key";
        var model = $parse(label);
        model.assign($scope, false);` //output: $scope.dynamicLabelkey

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

1. case 1 )

http://plnkr.co/edit/sA85huMV3nYUJME8tSVx?p=preview

you know the name of `label` property in your data (the key)

```
    <div class="width50" ng-repeat="item in myArray track by $index">
       <label>{{item.label}} - {{$index}}</label> : {{item.vehiclecategory}}
    </div>
```

Javascript : 
I added a `label` attribute to your `$scope.myArray`. 
As JohnD explain, you have to use `ng-repeat` to iterate over an array and not use "$scope.first, $scope.second ..." (imagine if you have 100)

```
$scope.myArray = [{
    "productDetails": {            "productName": "productname1",            "qty": 5,            "pricePerPiece": 20        },
    "vehiclecategory": "abcd1",
    "label" : "My Data",
}, {
    "productDetails": {
        "productName": "productname1",            "qty": 5,            "pricePerPiece": 20        
    },
    "vehiclecategory": "abcd2",
    "label" : "Your Info",
}, {
    "productDetails": {            "productName": "productname1",            "qty": 5,            "pricePerPiece": 20        },
    "vehiclecategory": "abcd3",
    "label":"adresse"
}, {
    "productDetails": {            "productName": "productname1",            "qty": 5,            "pricePerPiece": 20        },
    "vehiclecategory": "abcd4",
    "label": "street"
}, {
    "productDetails": {            "productName": "productname1",            "qty": 5,           "pricePerPiece": 20        },
    "vehiclecategory": "abcd5",
    "label" : "city",

}, {
    "productDetails": {            "productName": "productname1",            "qty": 5,            "pricePerPiece": 20        },
    "vehiclecategory": "abcd6",
    "label":"etc"
}];
```

---

2. case 2 )

Maybe the name of the `label` attribute is not always the same like this :

```
    $scope.myArray = [
        {
             "productDetails": {    "productName": "productname1","qty": 5, "pricePerPiece": 20 },
             "vehiclecategory": "abcd1",
             "My Data" : "My Data",
        }, {
             "productDetails": {    "productName": "productname1", "qty": 5, "pricePerPiece": 20 },
             "vehiclecategory": "abcd2",
             "Your Info" : "Your Info",
        }, {
             "productDetails": { "productName": "productname1", "qty": 5, "pricePerPiece": 20 },
             "vehiclecategory": "abcd3",
             "label":"adresse"
        }, {
             "productDetails": { "productName": "productname1", "qty": 5, "pricePerPiece": 20   },
             "vehiclecategory": "abcd4",
             "street": "street"
        }, 
        ...
    ];
    // this array contain all the possible label name  
    var listoflabel = ["etc","adresse","city","street","Your Info","My Data"];
    // search on item if a label key exist and return its value
     $scope.getLabel = function(item){
          for(var l in listoflabel){
            if(item[ listoflabel[l] ]){
              return item[ listoflabel[l] ];
            }
          }
          return "label";
        }
```

HTML with function call

```
 <div class="width50" ng-repeat="item in myArrayVariable track by $index">
       <label>{{getLabel(item)}}</label> : {{item.vehiclecategory}}
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes. Will have to change the api accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but if I do, you might be able to solve it with [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). Check out the following example:

```
<div class="width50" ng-repeat="item in myArray track by $index">
   <label>({{$index}}) {{item.vehiclecategory}}</label> : {{item.productDetails.productName}}
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. The label text will not be in same format, meaning not First Record, Second Record & so on. It will be different name which will be unique say for first it will My Data, second Test Info & so on. Since the label value won't be in same format i guess ng-repeat won't be an option. Let me know if still unclear

Comment: have updated the plnkr. I had to create 6 different scope objects. Is it possible to create scope variable dynamically say $scope.label + "key" = my value for the key.