# I am currently stuck on how to display this array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the code I currently have. I am having issues displaying the ordinals as I am not sure what for loop to put then in. Can someone please assist?

```js
var bandsString = "";
var newBandString = "";
var bandsListArray = ["Linkin Park", "Atmosphere", "Rage Against The Machine", "Immortal  Technique", "System of a Down"];

for (var i = 0; i < bandsListArray.length; i++) {
    var currentBand = bandsListArray[i];
    bandsString += "<li> My #" + [i + 1] + " band is " + currentBand + "</li>";
}

var bands = i;
if (bands == 0) {
    bands = i + "st";;
} else if (bands == 1) {
    bands = i + "nd";
} else if (bands == 2) {
    bands = i + "rd";
} else if (bands == 3) {
    bands = i + "th";
} else if (bands == 4) {
    bands = i + "th";
} else {

}

for (var i = 0; i < bandsListArray.length; i++) {
    var newBandList = bandsListArray[i];

    newBandString += "<li>My # " + [i + 1] + " band is " + currentBand + "</li>";
}


document.write(bandsString);
document.write(newBandString);
```

Comment: What do you want the display to look like?

Comment: I just want it to display the arrays in the html when I open the browser, I'm trying to display two different lists, which will somewhat be the same except one will say "My #1 band is..." and the other will say "My 1st band is..." and so on with the rest of the arrays.

Comment: You're close... you need to move your ordinals into the second for loop, so that i t gets detected every time. Also you should use normal brackets (ie`()`) instead of square brackets `[]` to enclose your arithmetic...

Comment: So would I place my ordinals after I declare my newBandString? and also, when running this code it only displays System of a Down below the first list<ul> </ul>

Comment: Looks like your if/else if conditions are mismatched with their bodies, such that you'll get `"0st", "1nd", "2rd", "3th"`.

Comment: Oh okay I forgot to put the +1, but that still doesn't display the bottom list the way I'm trying to

Comment: What do you actually want the output to look like?

Comment: Okay so now it's fixed seems like I put newBandList instead of what I meant to put which was, newBandString, so now the bottom list does display but i need the numbers on the bottom list to be in ordinal rather than how it is displayed on the first list.For example, I need the numbers to be listed as (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th)

Comment: Yeah I thought that was a mistake. I've posted an answer, see if that helps you.

Comment: Okay thats exactly what I needed! Thanks alot! Can you explain to me how the function works. What does the %10 / %100 do? And where did the "j" & "k" come from. I see that  it works perfectly I just want to understand why it works.

Comment: Yep, I'll edit my answer with some explanations.

Comment: Okay thank you very  much

Comment: @HenryMerida First, I don't get notified about comments on your question unless you tag me (like I did to you in this comment). If you commented on my answer I'd be notified even if you didn't tag me, but I'd have to tag you to make you get notified. Just a tip on how to use stack overflow :) Second, I've edited my question to expand on how the function works. Hopefully it's clear enough; if you need a better explanation just let me know and I'll see what I can do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but does this help? Instead of manually working out how to put the correct ordinal suffix ('st', 'nd', 'rd', etc.) on the numbers, I [googled a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13627586/2288578).

The `ordinal_suffix_of` function works like this:

This first part is the start of the function. Hopefully this is self-explanatory. We're creating a function that accepts one parameter, that will be named `i` inside the function.

```
function ordinal_suffix_of(i) {
```

This next part defines `j` and `k`. You can declare multiple variables while only typing `var` once by using commas, as this code does:

```
var j = i % 10,
    k = i % 100;
```

This would do exactly the same thing:

```
var j = i % 10;
var k = i % 100;
```

The percent sign (`%`) is called "modulus" and is a mathematical operator. What it does is divide the left operand by the right operand and returns the remainder. So in the case of `j`, it's being assigned remainder of dividing `i` by `10`. If `i` was `14`, for example, `j` would be `4`. If `i` was `179`, `j` would be `9`. The same thing happens for `k` except that it's divided by `100` instead of `10`.

What it's effectively doing is extracting the last 1 digit (for `j`) and the last 2 digits (for `k`) and then just checking (in the `if` statements) what ordinal suffixes they should have.

The reason for `k` is that you always want numbers ending in `1`, `2`, or `3` to have the suffixes `st`, `nd` , and `rd` ***except*** when the number ends in `11`, `12`, or `13`, in which case it should get the suffix `th`. So for example, `112` should be `112th`, and `313513` should be `313513th`. `k` handles this by making it so that if the number ends in `11`, `12`, or `13` we only add `th`. Note that `11 % 100` will result in `11`, so this works for `11`, `12`, and `13` as well.

```js
var bandsString = "";
var newBandString = "";
var bandsListArray = ["Linkin Park", "Atmosphere", "Rage Against The Machine", "Immortal  Technique", "System of a Down"];

for (var i = 0; i < bandsListArray.length; i++) {
 var currentBand = bandsListArray[i];
 bandsString += "<li> My #" + (i + 1) + " band is " + currentBand + "</li>";
}

for (var i = 0; i < bandsListArray.length; i++) {
 var newBandList = bandsListArray[i];

 newBandString += "<li>My " + ordinal_suffix_of(i + 1) + " band is " + newBandList + "</li>";
}

function ordinal_suffix_of(i) {
    var j = i % 10,
        k = i % 100;
    if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
        return i + "st";
    }
    if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
        return i + "nd";
    }
    if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
        return i + "rd";
    }
    return i + "th";
}


document.write(bandsString);
document.write(newBandString);
```

Comment: okay I understand it now, but for the K why is it necessary if all of the if statements show that it's not equal to K? Sorry by the way I'm new to coding so its a bit hard to understand it right away

Comment: In other words, couldn't this function work without involving the variable  K?

Comment: @HenryMerida Edited my answer. Let me know if that doesn't explain it well enough for you :)

Comment: Oh Okay that helped understand it much better thank you for your time I really appreciate it. You, and everyone else where  a great help!

Comment: @HenryMerida No worries man! I enjoy helping people understand programming, and all the cool and interesting things you can do with it :) Plus I'm at work and this is a lot more interesting than setting up products on a website haha!

Comment: Haha! Yeah that's one of the things I've come to love about coding, the problem solving. It can be a bit of a headache at times but once it clicks its a great feeling. So you'll probably see more questions coming from me soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just make the code more simple

```
var bandsString = "";
var newBandString = "";
var bandsListArray = ["Linkin Park", "Atmosphere", "Rage Against The Machine", "Immortal  Technique", "System of a Down"];

for (var i = 0; i < bandsListArray.length; i++) {
   var currentBand = bandsListArray[i];
   bandsString += "<li> My #" + [i + 1] + " band is " + currentBand + "</li>";        
   newBandString += "<li> My #" + numeric(i+1) + " band is " + currentBand + "</li>";
}

function numeric(i){
   var bands = i+"th";
  if (i == 1) {
    bands = i + "st";;
  } else if (i == 2) {
    bands = i + "nd";
  } else if (i == 3) {
    bands = i + "rd";
  } 
  return bands;
}
document.write(bandsString);
document.write(newBandString);
```

Comment: Be aware that that `numeric` function only works for numbers as high as 20. It will output `21th`, `22th`, `23th`, etc. Not knocking your arrangement of the OP's code, @TimothyLee, just making sure people seeing this realise :)

Comment: Oh thanks for reminding! It's 21st,22nd,23rd,24th...etc.So change the numeric() to your ordinal_suffix_of() will be correct.

Comment: Sure will! But it's not my `ordinal_suffix_of`, I got it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13627586/2288578).

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are trying to achieve is:

> My 2nd band is Atmosphere

Then this how you might achieve it

```
var bandsString = "";
var newBandString = "";
var bandsListArray = ["Linkin Park", "Atmosphere", "Rage Against The Machine", "Immortal  Technique", "System of a Down"];

for (var i = 0; i < bandsListArray.length; i++) {
    var currentBand = bandsListArray[i];
    bandsString += "<li> My #" + (i + 1) + " band is " + currentBand + "</li>";
    newBandString += "<li>My " + numberSuffix(i + 1) + " band is " + currentBand + "</li>";
}

function numberSuffix(number){
        if(number % 10==1) return number+'st';
        if(number % 10==2) return number+'nd';
        if(number % 10==3) return number+'rd';
        return number+'th';
}

document.write(bandsString);
document.write(newBandString);
```

Comment: Your `numberSuffix` function won't work on numbers above 100, just FYI.

Comment: thanks... your answer is more appropriate... just trying to make it simpler

Comment: Yeah no worries, that's a good idea and will probably help other people in future :)