# How do you format the date in the body of an email from Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an automated email script and in the body of the message is a date which is currently expressing `Thu Nov 28 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1300 (NZDT)` but I would like it expressed `28 November 2019`.

Below is my code. The code regarding the date is:

```
 var date = sheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
 var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "dd MMMMM yyyy")
```

```js
//Email Alerts for H&S Reviews
function sendEmails() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("H&S Reviews").activate();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var message = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Email Alerts").getRange(1,1).getValue();

  for (var i = 4;i<=lastRow;i++){

    var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
    var firstName = sheet.getRange(i, 10).getValue();
    var todaysDate = sheet.getRange(1, 11).getValue();
    var date = sheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "dd MMMMM yyyy")
    var task = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    var description = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    var messageBody = message.replace("{name}",firstName).replace("{Task}",task).replace("{Description}",description).replace("{Date}",date);
    var subject = "Health & Safety Review Task"; 
    var sendDate = sheet.getRange(i, 11).getValue();
    var sheetDate = new Date(sendDate);
    Sdate=Utilities.formatDate(todaysDate,"GMT+0200","dd-MM-yyyy")
    SsheetDate=Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,"GMT+0200", "dd-MM-yyyy")
    
    
    if (Sdate == SsheetDate){
      var subject = "Health & Safety Review Task";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, messageBody);
      
    }    
  }
}
```

I would appreciate some help regarding this.

Comment: You're already using [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) in your script. You can apply that to generate formatting like "28 November 2019". To get the ordinal suffixes, consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13627586/1329498).

Comment: You're missing the timeZone parameter.  `Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT+0200", "dd MMMMM yyyy")`.

Comment: @Diego - sorry - that didn't work

Comment: Can you please add more detail? Was there an error or is it simply not appearing how you want it?

Comment: Sorry. No error. It's not appearing how I want it

Comment: Again, that's not enough detail for us to help you.

Comment: It's still presenting the same format in the email Thu Nov 28 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1300 (NZDT)

Comment: Did you update your `replace()` calls to use the formatted date?

Comment: Sorry - no - have now and perfect - thank you for your help

Comment: @Diego - did you want to present the new code so I could the question as resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already using [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) in your script. You can apply that to generate formatting like "28 November 2019". To get the ordinal suffixes, consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13627586/1329498).

If you're okay with the "28 November 2019" format, then simply change these two lines

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT+0200", "dd MMMMM yyyy");
// ... other code ...
var messageBody = message.replace("{name}",firstName).replace("{Task}",task).replace("{Description}",description).replace("{Date}",formattedDate);
```

Your final code would be:

```
//Email Alerts for H&S Reviews
function sendEmails() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("H&S Reviews").activate();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var message = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Email Alerts").getRange(1,1).getValue();

  for (var i = 4;i<=lastRow;i++){

    var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
    var firstName = sheet.getRange(i, 10).getValue();
    var todaysDate = sheet.getRange(1, 11).getValue();
    var date = sheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT+0200", "dd MMMMM yyyy");
    var task = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    var description = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    var messageBody = message.replace("{name}",firstName).replace("{Task}",task).replace("{Description}",description).replace("{Date}",formattedDate);
    var subject = "Health & Safety Review Task"; 
    var sendDate = sheet.getRange(i, 11).getValue();
    var sheetDate = new Date(sendDate);
    Sdate=Utilities.formatDate(todaysDate,"GMT+0200","dd-MM-yyyy")
    SsheetDate=Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,"GMT+0200", "dd-MM-yyyy")


    if (Sdate == SsheetDate){
      var subject = "Health & Safety Review Task";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, messageBody);

    }    
  }
}
```