# How to convert new Date() to "Long Date (in the format like 1st January, 2020)"?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I want to display the current date in the format `1st January, 2020` or `January 1st, 2020`. From `new Date()`, I get something like `Wed Jun 10 2020 22:05:14...`. How do I convert that to `Jun 10th, 2020`?

Comment: Hey! this might be a duplicate of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date 
There you can find the answers to the problem you are currently having

Comment: There is no native js function to do that, but here is a possible answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627308/add-st-nd-rd-and-th-ordinal-suffix-to-a-number] --- Add st-nd-rd-th suffix to number)