# Node js - Adding ordinal suffix if a record already exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

As you can see below , I have a query that checks if the filename already exist and just add a timestamp to make it unique , now the timestamp is too long , I supposed wanted to use ordinal suffix instead of timestamp. How do we add an oridinal suffix everytime an existing file is found ?

Something like hellofilename-1st , hellofileaname-2nd. etc

Btw filename is the column in the database.

#CODE

```
// check if filename already exists
  const file = await context.service.Model.findOne({
    where: { humanId: record.id, filename: data.filename },
    paranoid: false,
  });

  if (file) {
    const prefix = Date.now().toString();
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const fileParts = data.filename.split('.');
    filename = `${fileParts[0]}-${prefix}.${fileParts[1]}`;
  }
```

#code 2

```
function ordinal_suffix_of(i) {
    var j = i % 10,
        k = i % 100;
    if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
        return i + "st";
    }
    if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
        return i + "nd";
    }
    if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
        return i + "rd";
    }
    return i + "th";
}
```

Comment: This can help you @Mr. Mark Tawin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627308/add-st-nd-rd-and-th-ordinal-suffix-to-a-number

Answer (score 0):

You need to try to count all documents using regexp, and then if count !== 0, add the document with name

```js
`hellofilename-${ordinal_suffix_of(count)}`
```

I'm not sure which db you are using, if it is MongoDB, then you can use $regex in query: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

and method count: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/

Comment: I have using mariadb and sequelize

Comment: do i need all the count of the documents or just the count of documents with the same filename ? @maxim

Comment: Cause I only need to add ordinal suffix to a new file if that filename has the same filename on the databse

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin
Only docs with the same filename) About DB, for SQL there is keywords LIKE (for query) and COUNT and for sequelize should be similar methods

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin Hi, if the answer have helped you, you can mark it as Accepted)