# How to change the value of the index number of an array so that it would start from 1 instead of 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging

How do i make it so that the index starts with 1 instead of 0. Also how would i make it 1st, 2ed, 3rd etc. in instead on  1 2 3  etc.

```
<p id = "array"></p>        
    <script>
            var car = ["Nissan Skyline R34 GTR", "Toyota Supra A80", "Mazda RX7 FD3S", "Honda NSX Type R", "Nissan 240SX", "Toyoto AE86", "Subaru Impreza WRX Sti", "Honda Civic EG6"];
            
            var text = "";
            car.forEach(script)
            document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = text;
            
            function script (value, index, array) {
              text += ("My #" + index + " choice is " + value + ". <br>");
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: What is the difference between 0 and 0?

Comment: Why don't you just +1 to each element when you display it ?

Comment: Are you asking about (0.) , i.e. a non-integer value such as floating-point?

Comment: @JosephDoggie i am asking how to change the value of the index number of an array so that it would start from 1 instead of 0

Comment: Probably you should edit the title then, please.

Comment: @JosephDoggie can you help me

Comment: I edited the title, however it needs to be approved before it will be seen.

Comment: [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627308/add-st-nd-rd-and-th-ordinal-suffix-to-a-number) for 1st, 2nd, etc

Answer (score 2):

> How to change the value of the index number of an array so that it would start from 1 instead of 0

Just answering the question without asking why you want that: You can achieve it by inserting and deleting a dummy element 0.

```html
<p id = "array"></p>        
<script>
    var car = ["", "Nissan Skyline R34 GTR", "Toyota Supra A80", "Mazda RX7 FD3S", "Honda NSX Type R", "Nissan 240SX", "Toyoto AE86", "Subaru Impreza WRX Sti", "Honda Civic EG6"];
    delete car[0]
    var text = "";
    car.forEach(script)
        document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = text;

    function script(value, index, array)
    { text += ("My #" + index + " choice is " + value + ". <br>"); }
</script>
```